# Woocommerce for Wordpress: How to modify the order number/id?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have implemented WooCommerce to my webshop and have connected a CorvusPay gateway for online payment.

Now the problem that we are having is that Corvus requires my order numbers to contain characters (uppercase and lowercase) along with numbers.

I have seen and tried many plugins and filters on how to change my order numbers inside Wordpress, but whilst the order is being processed and sent to Corvus the number is still the same old post ID.

I am aware that WooCommerce uses Wordpress post IDs to create the initial order numbers, but how can I change this?

How can I modify WooCommerce so that it uses a specific method of order number generation, that is I'd like the order numbers to be e.g. "Kr-12345" and **not** "12345".

I need a way to change its method of number generation and not use a plugin like Sequential Order Numbers since that just changes the numbers in my Wordpress page.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `woocommerce_order_number` hook to filter the value however you want.  [This guide](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-add-prefix-or-suffix-to-woocommerce-order-number/) explains how to use it for simply adding a prefix and suffix.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
    $prefix = 'VK/';
    $suffix = '/TS';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id . $suffix;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```

So it looks like this would do what you're wanting.  You could just remove the suffix if you don't need it, or make any necessary adjustments to the format of $new_order_id.

Another thing to keep in mind is that if you're using a plugin like [PayPal for WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) it has an option to set an invoice prefix built in.

Comment: I tried out that exact solution, but the problem was that it was still not sending that order number to corvus; because, the first thing it does is get the post id, sets it as an order number, sends that number to corvus and then goes to my wordpress where it is modified by the filter.
The guide finishes with this: "WooCommerce provides another filter woocommerce_new_order_data that allows you to modify the order data just before it is inserted in the wp_posts table using the wp_insert_post(). We will look at that in another post."
But I can't seem to find anything related to this...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like another case of the developer of the gateway not implementing the gateway correctly. For my answer I am assuming that you are using [CorvusPay WooCommerce Integration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/corvuspay-woocommerce-integration/).

If you at the `process_payment()` function in **classes.php** you'll see that the plug-in always sends the actual post_id for the order to the gateway every time:

```
/**
 *  This method accepts payment request initiated by user, and redirects
 *  him to CorvusPay IPG.
 * @param int $order_id
 * @return array
 */
public function process_payment($order_id) {
    // Load options
    $options = $this->_getOptions();
    $checkout_page_id = $options[CpsiKeys::OPTION_CHECKOUT_PAGE_ID];

    return array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'redirect' => add_query_arg('order_id', $order_id, get_permalink($checkout_page_id))
    );
}
```

This means no matter what trick you try, you will not be able to overcome the issue without this function getting modified because the plugin always sends the wrong piece of information (or at-least in the wrong format).

There are a number of fixes for this:

1. (Recommended) Ask the developer of the plugin to add a field to the settings page of the checkout that gives the user an option to send a prefixed order id.
2. (Risky) Modify the plugin code and force a prefix for now. This is risky because the developer could update the plugin which would overwrite your changes, however seeing as the plug-in only gets updated every so many months it may be your only solution. Try changing the code to something like the following:

-

```
/**
 *  This method accepts payment request initiated by user, and redirects
 *  him to CorvusPay IPG.
 * @param int $order_id
 * @return array
 */
public function process_payment($order_id) {
    // Load options
    $options = $this->_getOptions();
    $checkout_page_id = $options[CpsiKeys::OPTION_CHECKOUT_PAGE_ID];

    return array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'redirect' => add_query_arg('order_id', 'ABx' . $order_id, get_permalink($checkout_page_id))
    );
}
```

Where `ABx` is your prefix.

Koda

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've tried out the code fix and it does change in the address bar, but while it is sending it just stops and redirects to my homepage like nothing happened. I have also contacted Corvus about this and hopefully they'll be able to work something out.