# How to manipulate the WooCommerce order key by removing the "wc_" prefix?

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to manipulate the order key by removing `wc_` from it.
Problem is, no matter what I do, `wc_` is not removed.

**Is there any way to do this?**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_generate_order_key', 'woocommerce_generate_custom_order_key', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_generate_custom_order_key($order_key){
$order_key = str_replace( 'wc_', '', $order_key );
return $order_key;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_order_key` **(Order Key)** and `post_id` **(Order ID)** fields are different.

- The **order number** you see in the WooCommerce backend is the `post_id`
  field of the `wp_posts` table of the Wordpress database.
- The **order key** instead refers to the `_order_key` *(meta_key)* field of the `wp_postmeta` table of the Wordpress database.

The `woocommerce_generate_order_key` filter is documented [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-order-functions.html#source-view.163) and as you can see you cannot use it to remove the **wc_** prefix from the `_order_key` field of the order. Here is the extract of the [source code](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-order-functions.html#source-view.163):

```
/**
 * Generate an order key with prefix.
 *
 * @since 3.5.4
 * @param string $key Order key without a prefix. By default generates a 13 digit secret.
 * @return string The order key.
 */
function wc_generate_order_key( $key = '' ) {
    if ( '' === $key ) {
        $key = wp_generate_password( 13, false );
    }

    return 'wc_' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_generate_order_key', 'order_' . $key );
}
```

**If you want to manipulate the WooCommerce order key** you have to use the `set_order_key()` method of the **WC_Order** class. [Here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.1004) you find the documentation.

You will also need to update the order `post_password` field in the `wp_posts` table.

So, *for example*, if you wanted to set a custom order key *(removing the **wc_** prefix)* for each new order you could use this function:

```
// removes the "wc_" prefix from the WooCommerce order key field for each new order
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'set_custom_order_key', 99, 2 );
function set_custom_order_key( $order_id, $order ) {

    // get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // gets the current order key
    $order_key = $order->get_order_key();
    // remove the "wc_" prefix
    $new_order_key = str_replace( 'wc_', '', $order_key );

    // updates the "_order_key" field of the "wp_postmeta" table
    $order->set_order_key( $new_order_key );
    $order->save();

    // updates the "post_password" field of the "wp_posts" table
    $post = get_post( $order_id );
    $post->post_password = $new_order_key;
    wp_update_post( $post );

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

**If you want to manipulate the WooCommerce order id** you have to use the `woocommerce_order_number` filter. The documentation can be found [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.480).

You can find some examples here:

- [Adding suffix and prefix to WooCommerce order number without using a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783349/adding-suffix-and-prefix-to-woocommerce-order-number-without-using-a-plugin)
- [Woocommerce for Wordpress: How to modify the order number/id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319712/woocommerce-for-wordpress-how-to-modify-the-order-number-id)
- [Add in a custom prefix and suffix to WooCommerce Order Number](https://gist.github.com/lukecav/78b68bb1f46168963adfe659303a3fa6)